# ginjo RFM NoMethodError: undefined method `name' for Hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

We have found an intermittent issue with the ginjo RFM Gem (https://github.com/ginjo/rfm). That doesn't make a lot of sense.

Wondering if anyone can shed some light on this.

The error is

```
NoMethodError: undefined method name' for {"name"=>"addr_full", "data"=>{"__content__"=>" NSW "}}:Hash /data/myi/shared/bundled_gems/ruby/2.0.0/gems/ginjo-rfm-2.1.7/lib/rfm/record.rb:129:inrescue in block in initialize'
/data/myi/shared/bundled_gems/ruby/2.0.0/gems/ginjo-rfm-2.1.7/lib/rfm/record.rb:129:in block in initialize' /data/myi/shared/bundled_gems/ruby/2.0.0/gems/ginjo-rfm-2.1.7/lib/rfm/record.rb:127:ineach'
/data/myi/shared/bundled_gems/ruby/2.0.0/gems/ginjo-rfm-2.1.7/lib/rfm/record.rb:127:in initialize' /data/myi/shared/bundled_gems/ruby/2.0.0/gems/ginjo-rfm-2.1.7/lib/rfm/base.rb:111:innew'
/data/myi/shared/bundled_gems/ruby/2.0.0/gems/ginjo-rfm-2.1.7/lib/rfm/base.rb:111:in rescue in new' /data/myi/shared/bundled_gems/ruby/2.0.0/gems/ginjo-rfm-2.1.7/lib/rfm/base.rb:108:innew'
/data/myi/shared/bundled_gems/ruby/2.0.0/gems/ginjo-rfm-2.1.7/lib/rfm/record.rb:171:in block in build_records' /data/myi/shared/bundled_gems/ruby/2.0.0/gems/ginjo-rfm-
```

Ginjo RFM extends Hash with a method called .name, the problem is 'sometimes' the method isn't there but we cannot work out why.
Ginjo RFM code has this method

The RFM code does this

```
 record.columns.each do |field|
        next unless field
           field_name = @layout.field_mapping[field.name] || field.name rescue field.name
```

the field.name is the issue. A hack we think will work is

```
rescue field['name']
```

NOTE: field is a Hash. That has been extend with a name method
They do this by overriding the .each method on the record.columns with the following which extends the Hash.

```
 def rfm_extend_members(klass, caller=nil)
    @parent = caller
    @root = caller.instance_variable_get(:@root)
    @member_extension = klass
    self.instance_eval do
      class << self
        attr_accessor :parent

            alias_method 'old_reader', '[]'
            def [](*args)
                member = old_reader(*args)
          rfm_extend_member(member, @member_extension, args[0]) if args[0].is_a? Integer
                member
            end

            alias_method 'old_each', 'each'
            def each
                i = -1
                old_each do |member|
                    i = i + 1
                    rfm_extend_member(member, @member_extension, i)
                    yield(member)
                end
            end
      end
    end unless defined? old_reader
    self
  end

  def rfm_extend_member(member, extension, i=nil)
    if member and extension
        unless member.instance_variable_get(:@root)
              member.instance_variable_set(:@root, @root)
              member.instance_variable_set(:@parent, self)
              member.instance_variable_set(:@index, i)
            member.instance_eval(){def root; @root; end}
            member.instance_eval(){def parent; @parent; end}
            member.instance_eval(){def get_index; @index; end}
        end
            member.extend(extension)
        end  
  end
```

They are extending Hash with

```
module Column
        def name
            #n = parent.index {|i| i === self}
            root.fields[get_index].name             
        end

        def data
            self['DATA'].rfm_force_array.collect{|d| d['__content__']}
        end
    end
```

I totally don't get why this would sometimes work and sometimes not. Seems worse under load in our production environment.

Also baffled why they have done this in the first place. But thats a side issue :)

Any suggestions?

Comment: OMG! A quick look at the repo, and I can tell it needs some tender love and care. Code formatting is all over the place, and that is a weak point, but I am totally allergic to that. Depending on how the mixed in the method or extended the class, I am guessing they extend single instances, so when you copy an instance, it will create a new `Hash` without the extension. But that is just a wild guess. Also, why don't you use the original `lardawge-rfm` (from which the ginjo version was forked). Its code seems much cleaner. Just a question, I have no idea :)